# different data at ech row UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to know how can I display different data in each cell of table.

In my case, I have a uitable which has 4 rows. I want to display name in first row , in second row address , in third row phone no. , 4th row email . any suggestions ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you implement your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can put a condition on the `indexPath.row` value. This is assuming that you're using the same view type for each row of the data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = /*  you data goes here */;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = /*  you data goes here */;
            break;
        /* your additional cases go here */
        }
    return cell;    
}
```

If you want different table view cell types for each row, you have to have different cell identifier for each one of them, and instantiate the `UITableViewCell` with a particular cell type that you need using a `switch` statement, or an `if` statement.

Comment: In this case, I'm assuming that you're not storing data in an array, of course. With an array it's easy, you can do cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0):

store ur data in an array suppose-arr
in cellForRowAtIndexPath method write -->  cell.textLable.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];